# Ants memory profiler how to find the cause of memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ants

My page is crashing after some time on Azure.

I have this snapshot summary:
[image]

Then I check Gen 2, and as far I understand we are looking for the one who is consuming the most memory or amount of instances:
[image]

I clicked System - Byte[] instance categorizer,  since it was consuming most of memory and got:
[image]

Instance retention graph:
[image]

I have no idea how to work through this here and come to my code and resolve issue in code.

Comment: Did you exercise the page a bit before the first snapshot? It seems to me that this initial result could just be a false positive due to the resource system lazy-loading the resource strings.

Comment: This is api, I found out which endpoint is causing the problem. So I used Apache jMeter to create around 20.000 post requests to the api endpoint and took snapshoot with profiler.

Comment: A memory difference involves two snapshots. Did you stress it before the first snapshot also? Perhaps not as many calls, but at least some.

Comment: I didn't do any stress before the snapshot. You mean I should do 500.000 requests to main page, then 500.000 to that endpoint?

Comment: You should do at least 1 request before the first snapshot and as many as you like between the first and second snapshots. That one request will ensure that any lazily-initialized data needed to process the request is loaded before the snapshot and thus will not show in the difference report. The byte arrays you see are likely created only once and then persist for the lifetime of the app domain, and thus are not the source of any ongoing memory usage growth. This makes them uninteresting and hides the real problem.